# IntelliJ switch statement using Strings error: use -source 7

Tags: java, intellij-idea, switch-statement, java-7

I'm trying to use IntelliJ (on Mac OS X) to compile some code I wrote using Eclipse. I've attempted to run the following code:

```
switch (category) {
    case "below 20":
        below20++;
        break;
    case "20 to 29":
        to30++;
        break;
    case "30 to 39":
        to40++;
        break;
    case "40 to 49":
        to50++;
        break;
    case "50 to 59":
        to60++;
        break;
    case "60 to 69":
        to70++;
        break;
    case "70 t0 79":
        to80++;
        break;
    case "80 to 89":
        to90++;
        break;
    case "90 to 99":
        above90++;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
java: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
```

I know that some of the answers will be: RTFE (i.e. replace Manual with Error). But I did. I've attempted the following:

- Preferences > Compiler > Java Compiler and added `-source 7` and/or `-target 1.7` to **Additional command line parameters**
- Edit Configurations: checked **Use Alternative JDK** and wrote in the directory `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home`

And it hasn't fixed it. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I know this is obvious because the directory is above, but *I do have Java 7 installed*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the JDKs defined in IDEA; is your JDK 7 in there? And is it used by your current project?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In case anyone still gets this error message after following the advice to check the File > Project Structure -> Project and set appropriate Project language level.

Be sure to also check File > Project Structure> Modules, to see if all your modules are on the correct Language Level:  (or the specific desired level).

There is also one more place where this can go wrong, which is: File > Settings > Compiler > Java Compiler. There you can set the project and module's java compiler version.

(For IntelliJ version <= 12 : Project Structure => Project Settings)

Comment: Up vote for `Be sure to also check` module language level

Comment: In my case i had the language level File > Project Structure -> Project set properly but need to set at the File > Project Structure> Modules

Answer (score 17):

At the Intellij IDEA you should also go to `Project Settings` -> `Project` and set appropriate `Project language level` there

Answer (score 0):

Remember that using Strings in switch statements is only supported from JDK 1.7 onwards.
The default project settings of IntelliJ might not be using JDK 1.7 as default. 
Change them from the project settings to JDK 1.7.